# Scheduling a job or box based on a recurring external event

Tags: autosys

We need to start a processing pipeline whenever an external event (say, an "update" notification) occurs, one or more times a day.

For a predictable or fixed number of occurences, we can set up a trigger or watcher job to capture the events and use them to kick off the dependent box with the processing jobs.  But what if the event can happen a variable number of times a day?  Basically, we need to restart the trigger/watcher job automatically every time the dependent processing completes, and thus be ready for the next time the external event occurs.

Can this be done in autosys?  The 'continuous' attribute on file trigger jobs doesn't seem useful: it only writes alerts to the scheduler log when we would like it to start a dependent box instead.

Answer (score 0):

a simple loop perhaps would suffice

insert_job: flag-file-watcher

insert_job: flag-reset
condition: s(flag-file-watcher)

insert_job: main-process
condition: s(flag-reset)

update_job: flag-file-watcher
condition: s(main-process)